# Can not modify an anonymous hash reference inside a subroutine

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine

I'm trying to modify an array of anonymous hashes in-place, through two subroutines:

```
my $hashes = [{
    foo => 'bar',
    foobar => 'baz',
    qux => { 'foo' => 'baz' },
}];

sub data_parser
{
    my $data = shift;

    while ((my $key, my $value) = each($data)) {
            if (ref($value) ne '') {
                    __SUB__->($value);
            } else {
                    $value = value_parser($value)  if ($key eq 'foo');
                    print "data_parser() ${key}'s new value is: ${value}\n"  if ($key eq 'foo');
            }
    }
}

sub value_parser { return('newvalue'); }

foreach my $hash (@{$hashes}) {
    data_parser($hash);
    print "foo is " . $hash->{'foo'} . "\n";
    print "foo is " . $hash->{'qux'}{'foo'} . "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
data_parser() foo's new value is: newvalue
data_parser() foo's new value is: newvalue
foo is bar
foo is baz
```

I expected that value_parser() modifies the data structure through the hash reference, hence in-place.
Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assign `$value` to anything. Add

```
$data->{$key} = $value;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused about `$value`. I thought if `$data` is a reference, then with `each()` the `$value` will also be a reference, and will point to the value, not being the value itself.

Comment: You're thinking of alias, not reference. And even if `each` returned an alias, you never assign to that var but `$value` (a copy of it).

Comment: If it did return a reference, you'd have to use `$$value_ref = value_parser($$value_ref)`.